# Syntax highlighting bugs of VIM 7.3 for BASH scripts

Tags: bash, vim, syntax-highlighting

I just upgraded OS from Ubuntu 8.04 to Ubuntu 12.04, as well as the corresponding VIM package. However, I found the syntax highlighting of newer VIM for BASH scripts is strange: (1) the colors of open and close parenthesis are different; (2) the color of comments seems wrong; (3) the BASH keyword in comment should not be highlighted. I have already add `let g:is_bash=1` and `syntax on` into my ".vimrc" file. I am not sure whether this is a bug of VIM or something wrong of my settings. Any solutions to this problem? Thanks.

The screenshot of wrong syntax highlighting.
[image]

The screenshot of corresponding correct syntax highlighting:
[image]

The new (wrong) VIM version is: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled May 4 2012 04:21:49)  Included patches: 1-429

The old (correct) VIM version is: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Sep 21 2009 11:21:42) Included patches: 1-245

Comment: Gah, please redo those captures so there's less wasted space on the right, so the font can be bigger and more legible. And do you have a question? Right now you're just repoting a vim bug, and this is **NOT** the site for that.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, all Bash syntax highlighters are broken in a thousand ways. This isn't unusual. You simply can't rely on editors to parse Bash correctly, the grammar just allows way too many complex possibilities. Vim does a better job than most.

Make sure you have the very latest syntax file from [Dr Chip's page](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/syntax/sh.vim.gz). It isn't always up-to-date in Vim.

I believe you're mostly noticing some basic error highlighting that was added at some point, which gets it wrong quite frequently and messes up your code with ugly red text. I noticed a new variable added a few versions back for disabling this that isn't documented yet. `let g:sh_no_error=1` fixes up most of these issues for me.

As a side-note, anybody using terminal vim especailly with a 256-color scheme should really be using [csapprox](https://github.com/godlygeek/csapprox). Whenever I see screenshots of that weird light-blue color mixed with yellow it usually means csapprox isn't being used. I have no idea why it isn't included with vim and enabled by default.

Comment: I can confirm that this bug has been addressed the latest version of sh.vim. I reported this exact issue on the vim_use mailing list last year: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/sh-vim-Aug-16-2011-array-highlighting-bug-td4842488.html ; I'm glad to see that it's finally fixed.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes I use the `zsh` vim syntax highlighting for `bash` scripts.  Not perfect, but helps a little.

```
:set ft=zsh
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 Vim 7.4, this command restores a proper single color to `#` comments.  Without that, it's as if the `#` was ignored: keywords, strings, and $variables get different colors.

Comment: This was an instant solution for me, thanks.